# Sort selected sections in fixed order - Space is no constraint

Tags: string, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I have a DSL which is written for a smoke testing program.  At the end of the program run, another program picks this up and generates a PDF report. (DSL is chosen primarily to switch between different formats)

After the title page, a summary of the results of the test suite is to be displayed.  So, I put a place holder there.

```
add table:summary header="Summary" columns: 2
```

And then on, at the end of each test case, I insert a row to this table as in :

```
add row table:summary values: "Entitlements Test, PASS"
```

Since the table declaration and the rows are scattered, I would like to group them all before running it by the DSL parser which does action immediately for each line.

Is there a better way to group the rows with the table and in the order that they are written by the program (time).

I have been breaking my head for more than a couple of days but couldn't get a better method than these lame ideas :

(All my solutions are terrible if I wanted to introduce more tables into the reports)

1. Load the file as list of strings into memory. Holding the pointer on the first table index, loop further (through the entire list) and insert rows in the next index of the table declaration pushing the rest of the list down - 0(n) for each row :-( After the entire list has been traversed, search for the next table pointer and repeat the process.  If the list has reached its end without hitting another table, we are done.  I guess a balanced tree is a better option than a list here.
2. Put a prefix before "add table" say "t1" and rows as "t1r1", "t1r2" and preprocess the DSL before running it by the parser.
3. choose all the lines that starts with "add table" and "add row", store it in a ordered list. For each table, filter the relevant rows of the table and do a fixed order comparison. https://discursive.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CJCOOK/Fixed+Order+Comparison (I am yet to see what this does internally).

The entire file is not going to run more than a few thousand lines at the max and the reporting process is a dedicated process in itself. Therefore space should not be a constraint.

The entire DSL goes like this :

```
add header: "Smoke Testing Report for ..... (app name)"
add subheader: "on .... (date)"
add table:summary header="Summary" columns: 2
add title : "Login page"
add screenshot : "C:/projects/SmokingCPOII/geb-reports/Into_Login_page.png"
newpage
...
...
add title : "Entitlements Before Submit"
add screenshot : "C:/projects/SmokingCPOII/geb-reports/Entitlements Before Submit.png"
newpage
add title : "End"
add screenshot : "C:/projects/SmokingCPOII/geb-reports/end.png"
newpage
...
...
add row table:summary values: "Entitlements Test, Pass" 
...
...
add row table:summary values: "Another Test, Pass"
...
...
add row table:summary values: "Yet Another Test, Fail"
...
```

(Since the program is yet to be shown to anybody, I am free to change the DSL the way I want. However it would be great if we could make the DSL as human readable as possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your requirements correctly but I came up with this simple proof-of-concept, which seems reasonably fast to me. Mind you, it's not written in Java :(

```
 awk '/^add row table:/{printf "%06d|%s\n", hash[$3], $0; next}
      /^add table:/{hash[$2]=NR}
                   {printf "%06d|%s\n", NR, $0}' data |
 sort -sn |
 cut -f2 -d'|'
```

The "algorithm" is simple: keep a hash table from table names to line number. Every time you see a new table definition, insert the current line number into the hash table. For every line other than `add row` lines, output the line number as a prefix to the line; for `add row` lines, look the table name up in the hash table and use that instead of the line number. Then sort the output with a stable sort. [notes 1 and 2]

I tested it with this data file, which has two tables:

```
add header: "Smoke Testing Report for ..... (app name)"
add subheader: "on .... (date)"
add table:summary header="Summary" columns: 2
add title : "Login page"
add table:other header="Other" columns: 1
add screenshot : "C:/projects/SmokingCPOII/geb-reports/Into_Login_page.png"
newpage
... 1
... 2
add title : "Entitlements Before Submit"
add screenshot : "C:/projects/SmokingCPOII/geb-reports/Entitlements Before Submit.png"
newpage
add title : "End"
add screenshot : "C:/projects/SmokingCPOII/geb-reports/end.png"
newpage
... 3
add row table:other values: "Other 1"
... 4
add row table:summary values: "Entitlements Test, Pass" 
... 5
... 6
add row table:other values: "Other before 2"
add row table:other values: "Other 2"
add row table:other values: "Other after 2"
... 6a
add row table:summary values: "Another Test, Pass"
... 7
... 8
add row table:summary values: "Yet Another Test, Fail"
```

and it produced:

```
add header: "Smoke Testing Report for ..... (app name)"
add subheader: "on .... (date)"
add table:summary header="Summary" columns: 2
add row table:summary values: "Entitlements Test, Pass" 
add row table:summary values: "Another Test, Pass"
add row table:summary values: "Yet Another Test, Fail"
add title : "Login page"
add table:other header="Other" columns: 1
add row table:other values: "Other 1"
add row table:other values: "Other before 2"
add row table:other values: "Other 2"
add row table:other values: "Other after 2"
add screenshot : "C:/projects/SmokingCPOII/geb-reports/Into_Login_page.png"
newpage
... 1
... 2
add title : "Entitlements Before Submit"
add screenshot : "C:/projects/SmokingCPOII/geb-reports/Entitlements Before Submit.png"
newpage
add title : "End"
add screenshot : "C:/projects/SmokingCPOII/geb-reports/end.png"
newpage
... 3
... 4
... 5
... 6
... 6a
... 7
... 8
```

---

Note 1: It would be good to check to make sure the table name exists when an add row is encountered.

Note 2: It would be possible to keep both the line number and the number of `add row` lines seen in the hash table, updating the count each time you see a new one, in which case you wouldn't have to worry about a stable sort, although I don't think it's a problem to find stable sorts so I'd avoid the complication.

Comment: Thanks Rici.  I had to say that I never thought of this solution and this is way more optimal than my solution.

Comment: However, it would be great if we could avoid writing to the file anything that is not end-user friendly. Please let me build on your solution and try to hold the numbers in the memory (do a full scan first) and then remove it before spitting it back to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Finally,  I guess I found a O(n) way with O(n) space method

Create an empty list to hold the sorted values (sortedList) and an empty map to store the positions of the table declaration

```
    1) Loop through each line of the file  
    2) If the line of the file is a table declaration, populate it into a tableMap with key as tablename and value as line number
    2a) Add the line to the sorted list
    3) If the line of the file is a row declaration, take the line number of the table (in the tableMap) and insert the row line in the next index (in the sorted list)
    3a) Increment the line number value for the table in the tableMap
    4) If this is any other line, just add it to the sorted list
```